# checking existence of string in a cell MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, serial-port

I have a data as follows:
This is the sampled data order from serial port which going to come:

```
% date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:23,  t1:82.55,h1:85.60,t2:62.55,h2:65.60,
% date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:24,  p1:20,p2:35,
% date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:25,  p1:35,p2:21,
% date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:26,  t1:45,h1:65.60,t2:75.55,h2:65.60,


rdstr='date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:23,  t1:82.55,h1:85.60,t2:62.55,h2:65.60,'
```

Now, I would like to get the data to matrix var1 and var2.

```
var1= [datetime t1 t2;
        datetime t1 t2]...

var2= [datetime p1 p2;
       datetime p1 p2]...
```

Note: The readstr is a serial data received reading one line at a time.
the var1 datetime must be at their particular sampling times.

Comment: `rdstr` is not a cell, is a matrix in your example. Also it is not clear on what are `var1` and `var2`, I reckon you do want just to concatenate strings from `rdstr` depending on t1/p1/p2, am I right?

Comment: @Alessiox rdstr is the matrix which I get from fgets() from the serial port. Here I just want to show the next coming line after the first string in my example.

Comment: if you're working with a matrix, remove the "cell" reference from the title. Also, it looks like your matrix has only 1 row with all the `datetime` concatenated together. Is that it or it's just a minor typo and you actually want 1 datetime per row so you can scan the matrix row-by-row?

Comment: @Alessiox _rdstr_ is the matrix which I get from _fgets()_ from the serial port. Here I just want to show the next coming line after the first string in my example. _var1_are the matrix which the data of _datetime(numeric)_ and _t1 (numeric)_values ._var2_ is matrix _datetime(numeric)_ of and_ p1 p2_ (numeric)values.

Comment: I still can't quite get the structure of `rdstr`. Is that 1 row or 3 rows one per each datetime? There's something wrong with the string delimiters and commas. Please fix it.

Comment: I have a different sampling time for _t1h1_values and _p1p2_ values, which are 5 _sec _and _1sec_ respectively. so, I need to save the _t1h1_values at their particuar _datetime_ into the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have the entire file, I will use the data snippet you provided and I'm going to create a cell array (instead of a txt file) which we'll read line-by-line.

```
LINES={'date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:23,  t1:82.55,h1:85.60,t2:62.55,h2:65.60';
'date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:24,  p1:20,p2:35';
'date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:25,  p1:35,p2:21';
'date:2016-08-05, time:10:05:26,  t1:45,h1:65.60,t2:75.55,h2:65.60'};
```

Now we initialize `var1` and `var2` as empty variables:

```
var1=[];
var2=[];
```

Now we read the cell array `LINES` (i.e. your file) row-by-row (i.e. line-by-line) using a for-loop. Then we'll check using `strfind()` if a given string (`t1` or `p1`) is found inside the row we're checking. Finally, since your data is comma-separated, we'll use `strsplit()` with a comma delimiter to populate `var1` and `var2`:

```
for i=1:size(LINES,1)
    if strfind(LINES{i},'t1')
        var1=[var1 ; strsplit(LINES{i},',')];
    elseif strfind(LINES{i},'p1') || strfind(LINES{i},'p2')
        var2=[var2 ; strsplit(LINES{i},',')];
    else
        fprintf('t1/p1/p2 not found in i-th cell.\n');
    end
end
```

Variables `var1` and `var2` will have the form (respectively)
[image]
[image]

Finally, if you want to get rid of the `date`, `time`, `p1` (and so on) strings inside `var1` and `var2`:

```
var1=cellfun(@(x) x(strfind(x,':')+1:end),var1,'UniformOutput',false);
var2=cellfun(@(x) x(strfind(x,':')+1:end),var2,'UniformOutput',false);
```

and `var1` and `var2` will have the form (respectively):
[image]
[image]

If you don't need `h1` and `h2` values for `var1` you can remove such columns by means of:

```
var1(:,[4 6])=[];
```

**Update**: the file version.

```
% open txt file
fID=fopen('data.txt');

% init var1 and var2
var1=[];
var2=[];

% fetch 1st line
tline = fgets(fID);

while ischar(tline)
    % remove leading '% ', remove newline return and the last comma
    rdstr=tline(3:end-2);

    % same as above
    if strfind(rdstr,'t1')
        var1=[var1 ; strsplit(rdstr,',')];
    elseif strfind(rdstr,'p1') || strfind(rdstr,'p2')
        var2=[var2 ; strsplit(rdstr,',')];
    else
        fprintf('t1/p1/p2 not found in i-th cell.\n');
    end

    % fetch new line
    tline = fgets(fID);
end

fclose(fID);
```

where `data.txt` has the same structure as your data snippet and `var1` and `var2` have the structure shown in the first couple of figures. If you want to remove the strings `date`, `time` and so on you need to use `cellfun()` as above.

Comment: @Allessiox But when I get the data with fgets() or fscanf(), the _LINES_ is char array and not a cell.

Comment: @MaK correct. However we read this cell array row-by-row where the generic row is `LINES{i}`, but `LINES{i}` is a char array, just like your variable `rdstr` ;)

Comment: But while I running the script, This following error occurs:_Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object._

    if strfind(LINES{i},'t1')

Comment: @MaK, I suppose you're reading from a file, which (again, I suppose) is a txt file. You don't need the cell array (you don't have the cell array, that's why the error), that's just a way I used to simulate your txt file since I don't have it. You must change the for-loop (you might even use a while-loop) and read line-by-line not a cell array but your file. Read the file line-by-line, call `rdstr` the generic file line and substitute `LINES{i}` with `rdstr`.

Comment: @MaK I've edited the answer with the txt file approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have a question. How to get h1,h2,.. values into another variable with datetime say _v3_ =[datetime h1 h2]

Comment: @MaK, after `var1` has been created you can create `var3` by selecting the first (date), second (time), fourth (h1) and sixth (h2) column of `var1` and concatenate them together: `var3=[var1(:,1) var1(:,2) var1(:,4) var1(:,6)];`

Comment: But I guess this way wouldn't be possible if I have a few addition of h values i.e h3,h4  and so on..into the column. as this is serial data receiving end, addition of values could be expected.

Comment: As far as I can see from your attached data, there are no h3 and h4 so I didn't considered such problem. It's up to you to organize your data (here we saw the advantage of cell-array as an heterogeneous data structure) depending also on the analysis you need to perform with such data. For future questions on SO, please select a wider and more complete example.